# Save socket as type object and cast when used

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android

I am creating a crossplatform application using Mono that can use different kinds of connection types (Bluetooth, WiFi etc.) but at any given time it will always only have one socket connection.

What connection type is used is decided at compile time

I want this socket connection to be accessible to all my different pages of my application that needs it, then below an interface they will have their specific implementation (For example a Android Bluetooth implementation) that always needs android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket so I cast it to that.

So my Views and ViewModels dont know what kind of socket it is

My reason for this would be to able to hide it all behind one interface and just have a property

```
Public Interface MyContainer
{
    Bool Connected { get; set; }
    Object Socket { get; set; }
}
```

Would this be very very bad code? I can't find any other reasonable way to hide the Socket behind an Interface when it changes depending on platform and connectiontype

Comment: Why not expose an Interface through that SocketProperty, which all your different Sockettypes inherit from? (something like `ISocket Socket { get; set; }`)

Comment: But I cant add an interface to all these sockets? I am using sockets that are already implemented by the different frameworks?

Comment: I guess you could use generics as well. Would that be an option? (so, `public class MyContainer<T> { ... T Socket { get; set; } ... }`

Comment: I will look into it, just not sure how I would implement it

Comment: I will be using this way, it should perform better and its typesafe (Please create a real answer if you want to me vote your answer :) , cant mark that comment as answer )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your class generic to avoid using `object`.
So, for example you would use:

```
public class MyContainer<T>{
    ...

    T Socket { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and then use it like:

```
MyContainer<BlueToothSocket> container = new MyContainer<BlueToothSocket>();
BlueToothSocket socket = container.Socket;
```